# How to increase layer duration in Photoshop Video?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, video

I create a new shape layer in order to make a clipping mask for my video but the newly created layer lasts only 5seconds compared to the 16 seconds of my video and I can't seem to find a way to extend the duration of this layer, is there a way to do it ?

I would like to pull that to the right like the red arrow is showing but I can't it doesn't do anything

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to ungroup the shape layer and you can extend it as it pleases you.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop v**ideo layer/animation layers. On how to extend the timeline** (**hackaround**).

1. Layer> video layer > new video layer from file.
2. Select a video (.mp, mpg, avi... you name it) that last as long as you need it.
3. You have now an extended timeline to work with, video layers won't last longer but you can duplicate dem and create new ones and drag them around and have your work around.
4. Hope this helps someone. Best regards.

CHEERS!